# CLion files out of scope, CMakeLists

Tags: c++, ide, cmake, clion

My CLion doesn't seem to be working too well. Searching in whole project often results in: "usages are out of scope 'Project Files'". Similarly, most files appear to be grayed out, and the refactoring often does not understand certain pieces of my code are truly code.

This might something to do with the fact that all #includes use the <> with the compilation using the -I. flag.

THe project is actually build externally, so likely the CMakeList is the source of the trouble.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)
project(trunk)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(SOURCE_FILES <EVERYTHING HERE>)
add_executable(trunk ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm also having similar issues. I too suspected `CMakeLists.txt` to be the suspect as I use make for building. I then updated my `CMakeLists.txt` but most of my files are still greyed-out without many of CLion's cool features.